# A strange external device appeared on the left sidebar

Tags: directory

First it only showed up for a split second and disappeared, and after that it appeared again and stayed. It looks like this:

[image: It looked like this]

I didn't have anything plugged in at the time so I don't know where it came from. It had some files in the folders but I don't remember them because I was nervous and just ejected it. Is it normal? BTW I still use Ubuntu 16.04 but I'm planning to upgrade.

Comment: Did this volume appear after you uninstalled a snap?

Comment: No, it just appeared out of nowhere and that's why I am so worried.

Comment: Is your system 32 bit ??????

Comment: It says the OS type is 64-bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a small partition on your hard drive. In my experience, updating or upgrading another OS on the same computer can cause these small partitions to be shown or hidden to Linux. (eg, Windows 10 > Windows 11)

If you're curious, you can find out if it is physically located on your internal hard drive by running a 'mount | grep' command, then looking at the output. Here's how:

1. Open a Terminal
2. In the terminal, type this command:
   `mount | grep Wolumin`

This should return something like this:

```
douglask@doug-GxxxJM:~$ mount | grep Data
/dev/sdb4 on /media/doug/Data type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096,uhelper=udisks2)
```

I don't know how much you know, so I may be going too basic here. If I am, I apologize!

The part of the above output we're interested in is the /dev/sdb4 right at the start of the line. That refers to a special folder on the file system called /dev which holds special device files. [More info here](https://tldp.org/LDP/sag/html/dev-fs.html).

Devices beginning with sd are normally hard drives. sda is the first hard drive and typically holds your operating system(s), sdb is the second one and so on. If it's an sda, sdb, etc device, it's a physical drive. The number is the [partition number](https://www.howtogeek.com/184659/beginner-geek-hard-disk-partitions-explained/).

It's good to know how many drives are inside your computer as usb drives will show up as being beyond the internal drives. For example, my computer has sda and sdb inside it. If I attach an external USB drive, it appears as sdc.

If it's something else, that first portion of the mount line may give you a clue regarding the type of device, and what might be some good search terms.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I tried typing "mount | grep Wolumin" in the terminal but it didn't return anything :( I checked my dev folder but it doesn't contain anything named "sda" or "sdb". The PC came with Windows 10 on a single partition and I simply installed Ubuntu in its place from an installation disc.

Comment: Ok.  It's possible there's translation going on. Wolumin is another language for Volume.  In any case, these small volumes are quite common on systems that used to have Windows on them.

Comment: Other than using up a small amount of the hard drive space, it does no harm to leave it there.  This is my recommended course of action and is what I did for years until I had to replace the hard drive in my computer owing to a hardware failure.

If you want to look into this further, let me know and I'm happy to help.

Comment: Thank you so much, I was worried it was something malicious or something.

Comment: Happy to help. :) Enjoy!